# sprintf and allocating memory

Tags: c, malloc, printf, dynamic-memory-allocation

I have a structure where I stored some values as shown below:

```c
struct cmd { 
    char *pname;
    char *pdesc;
};
```

Following initialization I made as:

```c
struct cmd[] = {{"show", "show items"},
                {"exit", "exit the shell"},
                {"setitem",   "setting item"}
               };
```

I'm using `sprinf()` to print by storing all the pname ans pdesc as below,

```
int length = 0;    
char *resultcmd;    
for (indx = 0; indx< cmdCount; indx++) {
     length += sprintf(resultcmd+length, cmd[indx].pname, cmd[indx].pdesc);    
}
```

Please help me how to allocate memory for resultcmd, It worked when i make `resulecmd` as array of some length, but if more pname and pdesc are added buffer overruns. Please help me.

Comment: Use strlen to compute string length.

Comment: Can you count up the total memory needed before hand?

Comment: if using `glibc` and not caring about portability to other libc implementations, will say stick with gcc, you might like to take a look at `asprinf()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want safely output data to buffer `resultcmd` you have to find out its length before and use it:

```
size_t length = 1; // 1 symbol needed to store \0', 
                   // because strlen() returns length 
                   // without NULL-termination symbol
// compute length:
for (intx = 0; indx < cmdCount; indx++) {
     length += strlen(cmd[indx].pname) + strlen(cmd[indx].pdesc);
}

char *resultcmd = malloc(length);
int written = 0, ret = 0;

// print cmds to C string
for (indx = 0; indx < cmdCount; indx++) {
     ret = snprintf (resultcmd + written, length - written, 
                     "%s%s", cmd[indx].pname, cmd[indx].pdesc))
     if (0 > ret) {
         fprintf (stderr, "snprintf() error: %s\n", strerror(errno));
         break;
     } else {
         written += ret;
     }
}
/* 
 * some useful code here
 */
free(resultcmd);
```

Comment: don't you need the format argument for sprintf?  sprintf(resultcmd+length, cmd[indx].pname, cmd[indx].pdesc);     should be sprintf(resultcmd+length, "%s%s", cmd[indx].pname, cmd[indx].pdesc);  In reality, it should be a format that looks nice...

Comment: @thang Thanks. Fixed. Moreover, pdesc will not be printed at all without format parameter.

Comment: @Michael I think your usage of `length` is wrong. From the `malloc()` on, you either should reset it or use a 2nd "cursor" variable.

Comment: @glglgl Thank you too! Fixed now.

Comment: I'd rather do `int crsr = 0; for (indx = 0; indx< cmdCount; indx++) {
     crsr += snprintf(resultcmd+crsr, length-crsr, "%s%s", ...); }` in order to retain the original `length` and to have a bit of added safety.

Comment: And, yes, `size_t` is better than `int`.

Comment: @glglgl Thanks to all again! Added all your ideas to the answer. Must be fine now.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `snprintf(char *dest, size_t maxlen, char *fmt, ...)` to bound the size of your print.  If the function fails, it returns the number of characters that would have been written, had there been enough space; so that +1 is what you need to `realloc`.